# How to get a Kotlin KClass from a package class name string?

Tags: kotlin

If I have a string like `"mypackage.MyClass"`, how can I get the corresponding `KClass` at runtime (from the JVM)?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can use Java's method of getting a `Class` instance `Class.forName` and then convert it to a `KClass` using the `.kotlin` extension property. The code then looks like this:

```
val kClass = Class.forName("mypackage.MyClass").kotlin
```

A more direct way may be added at some point. The issue is located [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10440)

Comment: Note that this doesn’t work for primitive types like `char`.

Comment: It also doesn't work for types auto-converted types like java.util.List, kotlin.collections.Collection, kotlin.collections.Iterable, kotlin.Any, etc.  To get a KClass for those types, you need to call Class.forName() with their Java counterparts (java.util.List, java.util.Collection, java.lang.Iterable, java.lang.Object).  This is obviously not an exhaustive list.

Comment: @StephenTalley I noticed this too; `kotlin.Any` -> `java.lang.Object` -- seems the only workaround is a userland function of `forName` that validates/maps the Kotlin-world naming to Java.

Comment: Does it work for external app, if I have its pakage name?