# Kotlin - equivalence to SomeClass.class for objects?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to statically get an object's name (For logging uses)

The equivalence for:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private static final String TAG = SomeClass.class.getSimpleName()
}
```

In Kotlin:

```
object SomeObject
{
   private const val TAG = ?
}
```

Comment: It would be 'Clz::class.java.simpleName'. See official reference at  http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#class-references and SO at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340450/how-to-get-a-kotlin-kclass-from-a-package-class-name-string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
SomeClass::class.simpleName
```

Comment: What about kotlin.jvm.KotlinReflectionNotSupportedError ? Needs additional dependency to kotlin-reflect.jar. Maybe would be better use ::class.java.simpleName

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it in Android application, i would suggest you to do it like following: (packageName:className)

```
object SomeObject
{
    private val TAG = "${SomeObject::class.java.`package`.name}:${SomeObject::class.simpleName}"
}
```

Doing so you can ensure that tag name for any other class wont be duplicate.
It is really helpful, if you are creating a lib/code snippet that someone can use. Otherwise having same tag name may lead to runtime errors.

Comment: You can just use `class.name` to get the fully qualified name.

Comment: what if. in different package, a class with same name is there?